# Get Javascript reference to element with only backendNodeId from Devtools protocol

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want to be able to mouse over a page, have it highlight the elements underneath the cursor (in the same way as the developer tools inspector), and when I click on the mouse obtain the XPath for the element.
Enabling the element inspector and receiving the XPath to be done via code, and element selection by a human.

I can enable the devtools inspector behaviour by using [Chrome Devtools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) and using the [Overlay.setInspectMethod](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay/#method-setInspectMode) with `inspectNode=searchForNode`.

Upon a mouse click I then receive a [DOM.BackendNodeId](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#type-BackendNodeId) of the clicked element from the `Overlay.inspectNodeRequested` event

The devtools protocol does not seem to have any built in way to then obtain the XPath.
So I found [this](https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/49d3c595b07c438585ccecffde3c561d) javascript implementation of the Chrome Developer Tools Copy->Xpath functionality.

Whilst I can evaluate the javascript via CDT Protocol, after many hours of attempts, I cannot work out how to obtain a reference to the Node to execute the javascript function when all I have is the BackendNodeId.

Is there a way to get a reference in javascript to the node, or is there a way to get the nodes XPath in CDTProtocol ?

Comment: Use DOM.describeNode to traverse the DOM hierarchy and build the xpath as you go up.

Comment: Did think of that, seemed like a terribly inefficient way to tackle the problem. Was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I don't understand what's inefficient. You would need to walk the hierarchy anyway so the only added step is the command call. You can use promisify the call and `await` it for cleaner code.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that traversing the DOM via the CDT protocol (which is via a socket connection to the browser) would be slower that traversing the DOM directly via JS in the browser. I have not evaluated the perf difference and are just going on assumption. Were you thinking of using DOM.describeNode another way ?

Comment: There's only one way to use DOM.describeNode AFAICT. Indeed, if you need to make like 100 calls then you'll probably see a difference I guess, but normally it shouldn't be a concern. It's also safe, unlike running in JS context, where a site may redefine/extend some of the native types/prototypes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll fall back to a DOM.describeNode approach if I get no hits on this question for an alternative method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the proper solution

First I needed to obtain a reference to the Javascript object via

`DOM.resolveNode, {backendNodeId: nId}`

Then extract the objectId from the returned JSON object. Which will look something like [image: returned JSON object from resolveNode call]

Then I can call whatever function I like, with the element as context

`Runtime.callFunctionOn, {functionDeclaration: "function(){getXPathForElement(this)}", objectId: "{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":3}"`

Comment: Great finding. How did you get `Runtime.callFunctionOn` working? If I run your code snipet on my objectId I got a `ReferenceError: getXPathForElement is not defined↵…` How did you declare `getXPathForElement` in the Runtime context?

Comment: For my testing I used the getXpathForElement function from from https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/49d3c595b07c438585ccecffde3c561d. I then use the EvaluateExpression function of the Puppeteer page object to load it into the runtime ctx. HTH